# How to animate a simple 3D shape using Helix Toolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm trying to animate a simple rectangular shape so that it scales in size in a certain direction. As it is, I am making a rectangle that extends from point A to B. **The end goal is to animate it so that it starts at A and is transformed to be the length required to get to B.**

I'm pretty new to animation in general, so this process seems finicky to me.

Right now I am:

```
Creating a vector between the start and end point
Finding the 8 corners of the rectangle along that vector
Creating 2 triangles for each face of the rectangle
Rendering the shape
```

This is all being done by using a `MeshBuilder` object and adding the triangles and points individually.

So, the way I'm creating the prism doesn't really help for what I need to do. Ideally I suppose, I would just create a short prism aligned between the points, and then just extend the rectangle to be the right length in an animation.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this is a sense by scaling the 3D object from a size of 0 in the X/Y/Z to 1.0. So instead of the prism "extending" from A to B, it more or less "grows" to B.

Note that the `ScaleTransform3D` needed to have the `CenterXYZ` properties set to the coordinates of point A in order for it to be anchored to the correct position.

If I find a better solution, I'll update this answer later.